# How to update/modify existing 'aws_route53_record' CNAME to ALIAS with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

I want to update the existing 'aws_route53_record' from CNAME to Alias. What would be the proper process? It is even possible to make such update at once, or it needs to be done in two steps, like create a new ALIAS record and then delete CNAME record?
For example let's assume this it is the existing resource code.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  count.  = var.rds_enabled
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name    = var.record_name.data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = module.rds_aurora_postgress.rdscluster_endpoint
  provider = "aws.dns"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a new alias record. What you would want to do is to change the existing `aws_route53_record` resource to alias, so:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  count  = var.rds_enabled
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name    = var.record_name.data.aws_route53_zone.zone.name
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name      = module.rds_aurora_postgress.endpoint
    zone_id   = module.rds_aurora_postgress.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

Note: for the `endpoint` and `hosted_zone_id`, see [`aws_db_instance`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#hosted_zone_id)` resource docs.

If you do the changes on the resource, Terraform will detect it as [tainted](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/taint). This means that it will automatically destroy it and recreate it with a single apply.

Comment: This is what I have but it is not working, I am getting this error: Error: [ERR]: Error building change set: InvalidChangeBatch: [RRset of type A with DNS name bla.bla.bla.net it is not permitter because of a conflicting RRSet of type CNAME with the same DNS name already exists in zone ]

Comment: @Ervin Szilagyi,so mine issue it is the same like this one but CNAME to A :https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9732

Comment: I think you don't have a lifecycle rule set on the resource. Did Terraform attempt at least to destroy the CNAME record at first apply? If it did, you may want to apply the plan again, it might succeed at second try. Theoretically, this should be a one step change, but unfortunately this does not work out all of the time.

Comment: If something else in the dependency chain for this resource has `create_before_destroy = true` set then it may force Terraform to do the same for this object in order to avoid a dependency cycle, which would therefore cause a conflict. You can recognize that in the plan by Terraform showing it as `+/-` (create, then destroy) instead of `-/+` (destroy, then create)

Comment: FWIW the concept of "tainted" shouldn't come into play here because that's only for objects whose creation step failed, but I think you mean that Terraform will plan to replace it, which would indeed be true if the change here is one which the provider indicates it can't make as an in-place update.